# Duda sobre Callback en setCellValueFactory, Tableview JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, callback, observable

Estoy creando una `TableView` en JavaFX y quiero agregarle las propiedades a cada columna.
Como tengo 12 columnas con los mismos formatos (representan meses) y tengo los datos a mostrar dentro de un arreglo, y la misma está dentro de una clase, intento hacer un ciclo para aplicar el llenado de las celdas con `setCellValueFactory`.

Así por ejemplo, la columna 0, debería consultar el dato con la función `Persona.getDato(1)`, que retorna una valor de tipo `SimpleStringProperty`.

Por lo tanto, mi código queda más o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i=1; i<13;i++){
int finalI = i;
tableView.getColumns().get(i-1).setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Persona, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Persona, String> param) {
                    return param.getValue().getDato(finalI);
                }
            });
}
```

Para realizar este código me basé en la documentación de OpenJFX: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback).

Con éste código no puedo ejecutar mi programa, recibiendo el siguiente error:

> java: incompatible types: <anonymous javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Persona,java.lang.String>,javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<java.lang.String>>> cannot be converted to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Persona,capture#1 of ?>,javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<capture#1 of ?>>

Al cambiar el código por lambda y castear el TableColumn al tipo de dato `<Persona,String>`, el programa funciona y estira todos lo datos correctamente:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
         int finalI = i;
         ((TableColumn<Persona,String>)tableView.getColumns().get(i-1)).setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().getDato(finalI));
}
```

Pero una advertencia de [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) se mantiene dentro del código con el siguiente mensaje:

> Casting 'tbv.getColumns().get(...)' to 'TableColumn<Persona,String>' is redundant

Pero si borro el casting no funciona el código.
Quisiera entender por qué no funciona y cuál sería la mejor manera de implementar lo que necesito hacer.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: no entiendo para qué quiere hacer un loop ?

Comment: quiere inyectar todos los campos de un objeto en una fila de una tabla ?

Comment: Dentro de la clase persona tengo un arreglo llamado "Meses" de longitud 12, la idea es que cada columna tome el valor que se encuentra dentro de un índice del arreglo. (algo así como `Col0.getvalue(Persona.meses[0]))` El loop es para evitar escribir el mismo código 12 veces, ya que lo único que cambia en cada columna es el índice de donde está el dato que tiene que mostar.

Comment: implementando una tabla  bien se necesita  un solo método para inyectar toda la fila sin hacer loops es `TableView.getItems.add()`  hay que darle el tipo que se especifica en la tabla

Comment: Lo que se hace es dar objetos a tableview, no a tablecolumn.,en tablecolumn se establece cómo deben mostrarce las propiedades del objeto que se pasa a tableview. Por ejemplo un boolean se pasa a tableview y en tablecolumn se puede hacer que ese boolean se muestre como choicebox